# akka-http: complete request with flow

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

Assume I have set up an arbitrarily complex `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Unit]`.

I can already use said flow to handle incoming requests with

```
Http().bindAndHandle(flow, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

Now I would like to add logging, leveraging some existing directive, like `logRequestResult("my-service"){...}`
Is there a way to combine this directive with my flow? I guess I am looking for another directive, something along the lines of

```
def completeWithFlow(flow: Flow): Route
```

Is this possible at all?

N.B.: logRequestResult is an example, my question applies to any Directive one might find useful.

Comment: Why does logging have to be provided by a Directive?  Why can't you just use Flow.log?

Comment: Yes, I could use Flow.log for that specific example. my question was a bit more generic, as in: if I have a ready-to-use directive I would like to leverage, how can I reuse it in my context? Let's say I want to handle .favicon requests leveraging the directives below

path("favicon.ico") { 
getFromResource("favicon.ico", `image/x-icon`)
}

I would like to be able to use this directive in combination with my flow, e.g. use my flow to serve a specific path, and use the directive above to serve /favicon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out one (and maybe the only) way is to wire and materialize a new flow, and feed the extracted request to it. Example below

```
  val myFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed] = ???

  val route =
    get {
      logRequestResult("my-service") {
        extract(_.request) { req ⇒
          val futureResponse = Source.single(req).via(myFlow).runWith(Sink.head)
          complete(futureResponse)
        }
      }
    }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "127.0.0.1", 9000)
```

Comment: is this still the status in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/http/routing-dsl/overview.html

Are you looking for `route2HandlerFlow` or `Route.handlerFlow` ?

I believe `Route.handlerFlow` will work based on `implicit`s.

eg /

```
val serverBinding = Http().bindAndHandle(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080, 
handler = route2HandlerFlow(mainFlow()))
```

Comment: Thank you, I am in fact looking for the opposite.

Comment: :) Always glad to be of help... to someone... maybe