# connect Akka HTTP to Akka stream

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I would like to build a REST service with Akka HTTP that connect to an existing Sink (with Kafka reactive stream) but I cannot figure out how to chain an HTTP flow to an Akka stream sink...

Should I go for the low level Akka HTTP API that use Flows ?

My requirement is to have:

- backpressure on the complete flow
- 200 response code when all events are acknowledged by kafka sink
- 500 when backpressure is too high ? Is it possible ?

Here is my code current code

```
// flow to split group of lines into lines
  val splitLines = Flow[String].mapConcat(_.split("\n").toList)

// sink to produce kafka records in kafka
val kafkaSink = Flow[String]
    .map(new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String](topic, _))
    .toMat(Producer.plainSink(ProducerSettings(system,new ByteArraySerializer, new StringSerializer)))(Keep.right)

val routes = {
    path("ingest") {
      post {
        logger.info("starting ingestion")
        entity(as[GenericEvent]) { eventIngest =>
          ????      
        }~
        entity(as[GenericEventList]) { eventIngestList =>
          ????
        }
      }
    }
  }

Http(actorSystem).bindAndHandle(routes, config.httpInterface, config.httpPort)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of going about this. One suggestion could be to stream the data straight from your request entity into your kafka sink. The `extractDataBytes` directive helps you do exactly that (more info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/extractDataBytes.html)).

Try something along the lines of the example below. I added a `???` flow to allow for your case-specific transformation to correctly split/transform your request entity bytes. You can use the likes of `Framing.delimiter` to split the entity byte stream (more info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-io.html)).

```
  (extractDataBytes & extractMaterializer) { (byteSrc, mat) =>
    val f = byteSrc.via(???).runWith(kafkaSink)(mat)
    onComplete(f){
      case Success(value) => complete(s"OK")
      case Failure(ex)    => complete((StatusCodes.InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, if you want to unmarshal your entity to some domain object, you can do something like

```
  (entity(as[Event]) & extractMaterializer) { (event, mat) =>
    val f = Source.single(event).via(???).runWith(kafkaSink)(mat)
    onComplete(f){
      case Success(value) => complete(s"OK")
      case Failure(ex)    => complete((StatusCodes.InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
    }
  }
```

To come to your last question, should Kafka backpressure, your stream will never complete. You should expect the server to give you back a 500 after the configured request-timeout (citing the docs below):

> A default request timeout is applied globally to all routes and can be
>   configured using the akka.http.server.request-timeout setting (which
>   defaults to 20 seconds).

Comment: is there any way to unmarshall the stream with entity(as[event]) ?

Comment: yes, you can always run your unmarshalled event against the kafka sink. I have put another example in the answer

Comment: this is a new flow in the Akka HTTP flow, doesn't t introduce some useless overhead ?

Comment: if you want to keep using the high-level routing DSL it's the only possible way at the moment. See a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294428/akka-http-complete-request-with-flow. If you are that concerned about the materialization overhead, you should consider moving to the low-level DSL (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.0/scala/http/introduction.html#low-level-http-server-apis).