# Akka HTTP and Akka streams - using Flows with high level routes API

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http, akka-stream

This question has been asked for older versions of Akka Streams & Akka HTTP. [akka-http: complete request with flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294428/akka-http-complete-request-with-flow) the problem with this answer is for each flow you need to materialise a new flow for each request which is not cheap.

A year later in the latest version what is the best way to integrate a flow with the routes DSL?

Again I have a complex `Flow` I'd like to add to a route, if I map the flow to a `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, _]` could I complete a route with this flow? Is there a better way or is the only way to use the low level API?

If thats the case whats the best way to do route mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You are still required to materialize a new flow if you want to leverage Akka Streams DSL from a high-level Akka HTTP directive.

The good news is that [Akka 2.5](http://akka.io/news/2017/04/13/akka-2.5.0-released.html) changed the guts of the `ActorMaterializer` quite a bit, [allegedly](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/lightbend-podcast-whats-new-in-akka-2-5-with-patrik-nordwall?utm_content=buffer67ab7&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) improving its performance by 3-4x.

> Faster and more flexible Akka Streams materializer, which matters for
>   short lived streams, such as HTTP requests.